# Группировка функций внутри классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Я хочу сгруппировать несколько методов в разные группы. Все это я хочу содержать в одном большом классе

Что я пробовал сделать:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    class Group1:
        def method1():
            print('I am method 1 from group Group1, my best friend is ' + name)
    class Group2:
        def method1():
            print('I am method 1 from group Group2, my best friend is ' + name)
        def method2():
            print('I am method 2 from group Group2, my best friend is ' + name)
```

Эта идея сама по себе оказалась неправильной, проблема этого ужасного способа была в том, что name нельзя было передать из класса-родителя в вложенные классы

Хотел я сделать что-то вроде группировки методов как в vk-requests, там вызов методов реализован так:

```py
bot.messages.send()
```

То есть все методы имеют собственную группу. Поискав решение в исходниках того проекта, я мало что смог понять и пришел за разнеснениями сюда

Пока, все что я пытался придумать для того, чтобы это осуществилось, закончилось провалом. **Могу ли я сделать то, что я хочу и каким образом, если это так?**

Comment: Во-первых - непонятно зачем. Во-вторых, если у вас класс без полей и только с одним методом - то логично его заменить просто на функцию. В-третьих, непонятно что вообще родители делают внутри ребенка.

Comment: @insolor В своем вопросе я уточнил, что хочу сгруппировать **несколько** методов. Зачем - для решения своей задачи

Comment: В вопросе вы уточнили, что хотите сгруппировать несколько **методов**. Но группируете **классы**. Для 99% задач это не нужно. Вопрос "зачем" остается актуальным.

Comment: Или вы думаете, что это нужно для решения вашей задачи, но на самом деле это не нужно. Почитайте про [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy).

Comment: @insolor Прочитайте формулировку моего вопроса еще раз пожалуйста. Если я задал свой вопрос плохо или тп, можете на него отвечать, попытаюсь его переформулировать сейчас

Comment: Я уже прочитал вопрос, мне этого достаточно. Я могу сразу ответить, что вам не нужно делать то что вы пытаетесь сделать. Чтобы получить конкретный ответ, опишите конкретную реальную задачу.

Comment: @insolor Переформулировал вопрос, должно быть понятней?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае используется композиция

```
# Класс Messages может находиться вообще в другом модуле,
# не нужно его вставлять в сам класс, где он используется
class Messages:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    
    def send(self):
        print("Message sent", self.arg)


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        # Ниже создаем экземпляр класса Messages и записываем в поле объекта
        self.messages = Messages(arg)


me = MyClass(123)
me.messages.send()  # Вывод: Message sent 123
```

Как видим, класс внутрь другого класса вставлять не нужно.

К прочтению: [Наследование, композиция, агрегация](https://habr.com/ru/post/354046/)

По поводу vk-requests - можно найти проект на гитхабе и посмотреть как все устроено внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто группировать методы, то делай это по именам send(), send_to_console() и тд.

> Хотел я сделать что-то вроде группировки методов как в vk-requests,
>   там вызов методов реализован так:
>
> bot.messages.send()

Вообще это можно сделать так:

```
class Sender:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def send(self):
        print('send ' + self.message)

class Sender2:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def send(self):
        print('send ' + self.message)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.sender = Sender(self.name)
        self.sender2 = Sender2(self.name)


m = MyClass('asd')
m.sender.send()
m.sender2.send()
```

Но это уже ООП, а не простая группировка