# Как реализовать такой класс в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Очень необычный вопрос :)

Допустим, есть примерно такой код:

```
class One:
    class Two:
        class Three:
            ...
```

Что нужно:

```
print(One.Two.Three)  # выведет строку: 'One:Two:Three'
```

То есть, вся эта система из вложенных друг в друга классов должна при обращении к одному из них (Three в данном случае) выводить список всех классов, которые находятся выше, а также текущего (Three).

К чему я пришёл:

```
class MC(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return cls.__repr__(cls)


class Test(metaclass=MC):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return cls.__name__


print(Test)  # 'Test'
```

Данный код выводит имя текущего класса (Test), но нужно реализовать то же самое, только с учётом вложенных классов.

Спасибо!

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the intrusion - I can't read Russian, but I keep an alert for "Python metaclasses" questions. (I used automatic translation to read your question).  I had to come here to write that whatever is the source of your exercise, nesting classes in Python is not a useful thing. The only thing one can achieve are nested namespaces, but one gains nothing else with that: each nested class and their instances won't "know" about the parent class. And each instance of "class One" will have to create its own instance of "class Two" explicitly in its `__init__`.

Comment: Привет. Извините за вторжение - я не умею читать по-русски, но я держу оповещение о вопросах "метаклассы Python".. Мне пришлось прийти сюда, чтобы написать, что каким бы ни был источник вашего упражнения, вложение классов в Python — бесполезная вещь. Единственное, чего можно добиться, — это вложенные пространства имен, но от этого больше ничего не выиграешь: каждый вложенный класс и его экземпляры не будут «знать» о родительском классе. И каждый экземпляр «класса One» должен будет создать свой собственный экземпляр «класса Two» явно в своем `__init__`.

Comment: @jsbueno, got it, thanks :)

Comment: Если у вас реальная задача, и нужно обратиться к какому-то вложенному атрибуту, то это решается без метаклассов и вложенных классов, просто через композицию, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009741/1365. Если вы хотите потренироваться в использовании метаклассов, то это другой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой финт ушами

```
class Meta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        setattr(cls, "__qualnamemod__", getattr(cls, "__qualname__").replace('.', ':'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return getattr(self, "__qualnamemod__")


class One(metaclass=Meta):
    class Two(metaclass=Meta):
        class Three(metaclass=Meta):
            pass


print(One.Two.Three)
```